# Handling default std::io::Error in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm really new to Rust with less than a day of rusting. I'd like to know if the following code is ok or could it be written somehow better, and specifically, which would be the preferred way to handle the actual error case.

The return type `bool` represents whether a packet was received or not, so that the call to `tryReceiveUdp` can be chained using `bool::then` to do something else instead.

```rust
fn tryReceiveUdp(socket:UdpSocket) -> std::io::Result<bool>
{
    let mut buf = [0; 1024];
    
    let r = match socket.recv_from(&mut buf)
    {
        Ok((bytes,src)) => {
            handleUdp(buf[..bytes].to_vec(),src)?;
            false
        },
        Err(e) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => true,

        //Err(e) => Err(e)  <-- Is this better than the next line?
        e => {e?;true}
    };
    Ok(r)
}
```

**Edit**:
There's a mistake in the above. The code initially didn't have Ok(r) at the end. Instead the specific question was between these two

```rust
Err(e) => Err(e),  //<-- Is this better than the next line?
e => {e?;Ok(true)},
```

Comment: Returning `true` when nothing happened is very unintuitive for a `try*` function.

Comment: @kmdreko Yes, that seemed a bit questionable to me too. The idea is to do essentially this in a loop: `tryReceiveUdp(&socket)?.then(|| sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)));`

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good reason to me, nothing wrong with `if !tryReceiveUdp(&socket)? { sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)) }`

Comment: @kmdreko I'll eventually have more steps. The idea is that the loop would sleep only when nothing else is done. In C I'd just have a `bool` variable to indicate whether to sleep or not and check that at the end of the loop. I'm wondering what is the most rustic approach.

Comment: The "sleep(100 msec)" seems unfortunate. Much better to sleep until file descriptor becomes readable. Perhaps with `select()`, which is happy to accept a timeout of 100 msec if that's what you really need.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  It's best to describe **what value this code provides to its user**.

Comment: I am more concerned about the magic number `1024` in the buffer size than about the general code style. Where does this number come from? Why was it chosen? Is it gonna hurt me?

Comment: @RichardNeumann Yes, that is a bit sloppy. The idea is that it's large enough. I'll be receiving fixed size messages and I'll be able to check at compile time that the messages fit. I suppose I could figure out how to get the max size over all of the message types as a compile time constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path I would take with the error processing in this code would be to remove the `let r = ...; Ok(r)` and have the `match` compute the return value directly:

```rust
fn tryReceiveUdp(socket:UdpSocket) -> std::io::Result<bool>
{
    let mut buf = [0; 1024];
    
    match socket.recv_from(&mut buf)
    {
        Ok((bytes,src)) => {
            handleUdp(buf[..bytes].to_vec(),src)?;
            Ok(false)
        },
        Err(e) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => Ok(true),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

This has more duplicated `Ok`s, but it is easy to see at a glance whether each case is either a success or a failure.

As to the exact choice of error propagation operation `Err(e) => Err(e)`: I generally prefer not to use the `?` operator with a value *known* to be an error. In this case, it's simple to not early-return at all and just let the `match` pass the `Err` out, but in the case where an early-return is necessary, I'd still rather write `return Err(e);` or `return result;` rather than using an `?` that *appears* to unconditionally return. I avoid that use of `?` for several reasons:

- it's potentially confusing to readers,
- it contains a pointless branch that can never be taken (though that will of course be optimized out), and
- it requires you to write something after it that type-checks as if control flow *could* continue past that point (the `;true` in your code).

---

Other things I notice in review:

- Your function takes the socket by value, so you'll only be able to receive one packet. Consider taking it by reference instead (`&UdpSocket`).
- Consider importing modules to use shorter paths rather than repeating `std::` everywhere.
- Rust functions should be named with `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.
- Use standard code formatting, as performed by `cargo fmt`.

With all of those changed:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::net::UdpSocket;

fn try_receive_udp(socket: &UdpSocket) -> io::Result<bool> {
    let mut buf = [0; 1024];

    match socket.recv_from(&mut buf) {
        Ok((bytes, src)) => {
            handle_udp(buf[..bytes].to_vec(), src)?;
            Ok(false)
        }
        Err(e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => Ok(true),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't set up the loop calling this function yet, so the compiler didn't complain about the issue with socket move semantics. Good catch! 
I take it that you'd prefer the Err(e) => Err(e) over the alternative?

Comment: In C++, it's usually recommended to avoid `using`. And in Java & Scala it's preferred to import only needed items. In this case, there is std::Result, which is now shadowed by std::io::Result. Is Rust somehow different in this respect?

Comment: @TrayMan this code doesn't shadow `Result`, it only brings `io` into scope.

Comment: @kmdreko I see. So `use std::io` is not like `using std::io` in C++, or `import std.io.*` in Java.

Comment: @TrayMan It would in fact shadow `Result` if you wrote `use std::io::*;` or `use std::io::Result;` But the _only_ time `use` will bring in a name you didn't write explicitly is when you write `::*` (glob import).

Comment: "I take it that you'd prefer the Err(e) => Err(e) over the alternative?"  — I added a section about that choice to my answer.